# Allow max 10 items with same GUID

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

I have a table with 4 columns:

ID, GUID, Binary, Timestamp.

My goal is to save last 10 modifications of the binary into database. If the 11th modification is inserted, the oldest one should be removed.

My current approach is to do it in two steps (pseudo mssql):

```
1) DELETE FROM mytable WHERE GUID = 'XXX' AND 
   ID NOT IN (SELECT TOP 9 ID FROM mytable WHERE GUID = 'XXX' ORDER BY Timestamp)

2) INSERT new binary ...
```

Is there a way to do it more efficient, maybe with one statement? Is there a way to make it both, mssql and postgresql compatible (without TOP / Limit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following will work in both SQL Server and Postgres:

```
with todelete as (
      select id, row_number() over (partition by GUID order by timestamp) as seqnum
      from mytable
      where GUID = 'xxx'
     )
delete from mytable
    where id in (select id from todelete where seqnum > 10);
```

Comment: +1 for you, it turns out that delete from cte is not working in postgreSQL :(

Comment: @RomanPekar . . . It works on SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f1107/1).

Comment: @VladL . . . I don't think I understand your question.  But, Postgres allows `insert` in a CTE but SQL Server does not.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean my answer, SQL server allows to delete from cte.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I mean can I execute delete and insert as a single query or two executions are required?

Answer (score 3):

You could use cte for compatibility:

```
with cte as (
   select
       row_number() over(order by Timestamp desc) as row_num
   from mytable
   where GUID = 'XXX'
)
delete from cte
where row_num > 10
```

**edit**
see Gordon Linoff answer, my syntax is not working in PostgreSQL, just tested it in sqlfiddle. I'm working too much with SQL Server...

**edit2**
About delete and insert in one query, PostgreSQL allows that:

```
with cte_del as (
   select
       id,
       row_number() over(order by id desc) as row_num
   from tbl
   where GUID = 'XXX'
), cte_d as (
   delete from tbl where id in (select id from cte_del where row_num > 10)
)
insert into ...
select id from cte_del where row_num <= 10;
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/39d9a/6)

Comment: I don't think so, almost sure you cannot do this with query working both in PostgreSQL and SQL Server

Comment: @RomanPekar . . . Your original query doesn't work in Postgres, because Postgres handles CTEs differently from SQL Server.  Basically, they are not "updatable"; they are treated as instantiated derived tables.

Comment: thanks @GordonLinoff, it's always great to learn smth new, I wish I have a time to work with PostgreSQL more..

Comment: Huh, so MS SQL Server treats CTEs like automatically updatable views? Interesting. That could be quite handy.